# Regex for monetary values twice in string

Tags: javascript, typescript, string, foreach

I have this regex to extract monetary values from strings:

```js
/[$R]\s*(\d*,?\d+)?\b/g
```

It is working fine. The new problem is, sometimes I will have two monetary values in the same string. For example:

> Your purchase of R$ 447,71 was accepted. Your new balance is R$
> 20,31.

So, how could I do in order to extract both values or at least extract first one?
Because my regex extracted the last one...

The function:

```js
  treatMonetary(monetry: string) {
    let resultString = '';
    var res = monetry.match(/[$R]\s*(\d*,?\d+)?\b/g);
    res?.forEach(element => {
      if (element.includes("$")) {
        resultString = element?.replace('$', '')?.replace(" ", "")?.replace("R", "")?.replace(',', '.');
      }
    });
    return resultString;
  }
```

Comment: This is not a regex issue, you re-write the result in your `forEach`.